# How to a create a taller header on the first page?

Tags: fancyhdr, header

On the first page of an article I want to create a much taller header than on the rest of the pages. Problem is that the first page overflows at the bottom if I use the solution below. 
How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \setlength{\headheight}{190pt}

  \fancyhead[C]{
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\
    \vspace{3cm}
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\
    \vspace{3cm}
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\    
  }

}

\begin{document}

\title{Lipsum ...}

\author{Me, Myself} 
\date{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}


\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Btw, having header on the title page is IMHO not wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a zero height box (here represented by an image) for the header in the first page and the `titling` package in order to move down the title.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[C]{%
    \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=6cm]{example-image}}%
  }%
}

\pretitle{\vspace*{5cm}\begin{center}\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\title{Lipsum ...}

\author{Me, Myself} 
\date{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}


\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution because solves my problem in the preamble but  the text in raisebox is processed in LR mode so it cannot contain line breaks. My header contain three lines of text, some hrules and some images.

Comment: @HoreaOros Use a `\parbox`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest setting your page style to cover the majority of your document (pages 2+) and set the header for the first page as part of the main document, moving it place as needed. This way text will still flow naturally from page 1-2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}% Main document page style

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}% Page style of first page only
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\headheight-\headsep}%

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{example-image}% Your first page header

{\let\newpage\relax % Avoid page break due to \maketitle
\maketitle}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The first page "header" is moved up by `\headsep+\headheight`, but could be adjusted to line up with subsequent page headers, depending on what your first page "header" actually looks like. Of course, you could also define a different footer for the first page.

Since `\maketitle` usually sets the title at the top of a page, it issues `\newpage`. To avoid this (and hence connect the first page "header" with the title), we momentarily set `\newpage` to `\relax` - a no-op...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `geometry` package to modify the `\textheight` of the first page. `geometry` has a `\newgeometry` command which allows to modify the geometry (margins, height and width of text, etc.) from the point where the `\newgeometry` command is used until a `\restoregeometry` command is used. Note that the `\restoregeometry` command triggers a page break, so it should be used at the end of the last page where the `\newgeometry` is intended to be.

Also, I'm not sure whether it's relevant to redefine the `plain` page style here, since another page style can be defined. Here I defined a `firstpage` style and used it for the first page, where I also redefined `\textheight` to 320pt using `\newgeometry`. The 320pt might not be the best value, it could probably be adjusted more precisely.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt}%
  \renewcommand{\headheight}{190pt}%
  \fancyhead[C]{%
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\[3cm]
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\[3cm]
    \hrule\hspace{0pt}\\
  }
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\title{Lipsum ...}

\author{Me, Myself} 
\date{}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{textheight=320pt}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\lipsum*[13]

\lipsum*[2]

\restoregeometry

\lipsum*[3]

\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]